# Replacing column 1 in file1 with matching ID's in file 2

Tags: python, data-download, data-preprocessing

I have downloaded two files:

**File1**.csv from:
https://depmap.org/portal/download/data_slicer/download?file_path=20220227%2F3c335b7d-c18e-4788-b2e6-512d71f0a339%2Fexport.csv&name=Metabolomics.csv

**File 1** looks like

```
,2-aminoadipate,3-phosphoglycerate,alpha-glycerophosphate
ACH-000698,6.1127272,6.034197900000001,5.8968963
ACH-000489,5.5774126,5.7270453,5.1114679,6.07325
```

**File2**.csv from:
enter link description here
https://cog.sanger.ac.uk/cmp/download/model_list_20220205.csv

File2 looks like:

```
 model_id,model_name,synonyms,model_type
 SIDM01774,PK-59,,Cell Line,Adherent
 SIDM00192,SNU-1033,,Cell Line,Adherent
```

I want to replace ACH-* ids with SIDM* ids in File1.csv. The ACH-* id's for SIDM* ids are given in the "BROAD_ID" (col.no =40) column in the File2.csv

Desired output

```
,2-aminoadipate,3-phosphoglycerate,alpha-glycerophosphate
SIDM00523,6.1127272,6.034197900000001,5.8968963
SIDM00835,5.5774126,5.7270453,5.1114679,6.07325
```

I want to do this with python script. I tried some initial steps. Please forgive any grave mistake, as I am a beginner in Python

```
 import pandas as pd

 df = pd.read_csv("File1.csv", index_col=0).T

 print(df)

 models = pd.read_csv("File2.csv", index_col="model_id", usecols=["model_id", "BROAD_ID"]).rename(columns={"model_id": "Model"})

 df = df.join(models).rename_axis(index="Model Name").reset_index()

 print(df)

 df2 = df.set_index("Model").drop(columns="Model Name")

 df2.to_csv("Meta.tsv", sep="\t")

 df2.index = df2.index + ".Demeter"
 df2.T.rename_axis(index="Gene").to_csv("Meta_2.tsv", sep="\t")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was not sure about the exact output (columns) you desired. The following code should inner merge both data frames. It writes a copy of 'model_list' column as a first column. You could remove any unwanted columns. I am sure there are more elegant ways of doing it. Hope it helps. It's totally different approach than yours.

```
import pandas as pd

metabolics = pd.read_csv("Metabolomics.csv", sep=",", header=0) 
model_list = pd.read_csv("model_list_20220205.csv", sep=",", header=0) 
metabolics=metabolics.rename(columns={'Unnamed: 0':'ACH_number'}) #rename the unnamed column.
merged_df = pd.merge(metabolics, model_list, left_on='ACH_number', right_on='BROAD_ID', how='inner') #join two files

#insert model_id column at the beginning
#You will have dupicae 'model_id' column
merged_df.insert(0, "model_id", merged_df['model_id'], allow_duplicates=True) 
merged_df.to_csv('results.csv', sep=",", index=False)
print(merged_df.shape)
```

Comment: This looks about right

Comment: I agree with @M__ 's comment below. You would need to test the code make sure that merge on keys/columns as indicated give the desired output.

Comment: My pandas is rusty. The basic issue is that `joint` in SQL is `merge` in pandas. This might be why the OP used `joint` (except its pandas).  I was always told SQL `joint` merges via a common key and I carried that through into pandas.

Comment: I am no expert either. But I will look into this as I start using it recently more often.

Comment: Hi. I used the above script. There were two issues:
1.  I am getting a result file with 973 rows, while the original file have 929 rows.
2. I want only rows where a SIDM* code is available for ACH-*. Also in my desired output I don' t want the ACH-* code column.

Comment: Code should be do the right thing. If you inner merge, your results file will have 923 lines excluding headers. Now, you file has 928 record. You are missing the following 5 records from results.> ACH-000338, ACH-000467, ACH-000710, ACH-000833, ACH-001063. The reason for is that one moodel_list file has irregular entries. For example if you look at the col-40, you will see that actual cell entry is "ACH-000338;ACH-000338", not "ACH-000338" thus pandas cannot merge these.

Comment: Either you live losing 5 records, or you need write another script that considers this kind of anomalies or update the tables. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Supertech: Thank you so much for getting back. The script is correctly getting the 923 matching id's. But when I saw the first column with awk. There were extra entries in the first column from the random columns of `model_list` file

Answer (score 2):

The basic strategy of `merge` 'left' (which I think is default) is the correct thing to do. However, I would be concerned by lack of a key between the two data sets and basically the merging will take place on the row order. Within `merge` is `on=` then the shared `key`, in the code by @supertech there is left-on='ACH_number', I dunno because `ACH_number` does not appear to be shared. The code needs testing.

If you assign an index it will attempt to merge on the index (which I think will therefore fail). What I think you want is the row order 1,2,3,4 in each dataframe to be the key that is merged. Therefore not specifying `key` might be the right thing to do, what can happen is it will then use the row order as the left-key. I cannot remember.

The `insert` is correct to reorder the columns to get the desired output.

Finally you want,

```
del merged_df['column_name']
```

for each column you don't want. There is a way to loop through this, but the above keeps things simple. You then do the standard csv dump.

Note, see comments on `drop` by @GOATNine, which strongly preferred.

Setting and unsetting indexes is key to manipulating pandas but it is within a specific contex.

**Summary** the command `merge` and `insert` are correct with the addition of `del` however, the code needs testing regarding merge `left-on` and assigning the index. It is much easier to print the output and visualise it.

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining it so well

Comment: I do not know the reason why wget fails. Maybe someone else could help. I have clicked on the link on my Pc and it was sufficient to download. wget also failed for me.

Comment: If you're using pandas to drop the columns, you can just use df = df.drop(columns=['column1','column2'....]), or drop the assignment and use the option 'inplace=true' instead. This allows you to drop as many columns as you like at once, by making a string list of the column names.

Comment: Yes, I remember now. This is much better

Comment: Could anyone please update the code. I am a begginer in python and I am not getting where should I include all the steps suggested. I want file1 with all the columns except column 1 (ACH-* ids) replaced by SIDM* id's.

Comment: merge, insert, drop. I might test it if there are example tables (not links), or I was currently working with pandas. The info you supplied isn't clear enough for me so I can easily transfer it an IDE

Comment: @Megha see my comment under my answer. Your model_ file has anomalies in some of the cells therefore inner merge fails for 5 of the records.